# for loop an argument in function

Tags: javascript, php

I was doing this code but it will take time because it will be h1 up until h24 so i decided to use a for loop but i don't know how..

**this is my original code**

```
function hover(h1,h2,h3,h4){
  document.getElementById(h1).style.backgroundColor="orange";
  document.getElementById(h2).style.backgroundColor="orange";
  document.getElementById(h3).style.backgroundColor="orange";
  document.getElementById(h4).style.backgroundColor="orange";
}
```

**and i want to replace it something like this**

```
function hover(
  for(i = 1; i<=24; i++) {
    document.write("h"+i+",");
  }
)
```

but there is an error.. Please help me out.. Thank you

Comment: Well first off, those methods are looking for variables called `h1/2/3/4`. You did not set them at all

Comment: I had already declared it @RUJordan i just did not include it because its too long..

Comment: hello @davidkonrad any suggestions in looping the arguments?

Comment: It's not possible to build a list of arguments using a `for` loop. In your example you're attempting to create a single string.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton It's possible and pretty simple. See my answer

Comment: @Italy You're using a loop to process arguments rather than dynamically build the parameters segment of a function's definition.

Comment: @George Brighton "It's not possible to build a list of arguments using a for loop.", .. say again?

Comment: I think he's trying to create a function's parameter list dynamically, e.g. function foo(<logic to generate parameter list (for loop) here>) {...}. I'm trying to make the point that this isn't allowed - the way to achieve it is to use a solution like @Italy's which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: see my solution, it takes `n` elements, and have both hover and out, so indded it is possible

Comment: Indeed, but hardcoded parameter lists can't be created in JavaScript. When you write `function a(p1,p2) {..}`, you can't create the equivalent of `p1,p2` at runtime. Yes - there are ways around it, but not via writing in the parameters with `document.write()`!

Comment: Agree, and I think OP was saying he wants to get rid of document.write, which in paranthesis is useless or destructive here. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hover() {
    for(var i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        document.getElementById("h" + i).style.backgroundColor="orange";
    }
}
```

If you could need more control, you could set the upper limit as a parameter, e.g.

```
function hover(limit) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        document.getElementById("h" + i).style.backgroundColor="orange";
    }
}
```

A call to `hover(10);` would change the background colour of h1 through h10.

Comment: thank you for the reply but the argument is the one i actually want to be for looped..

Comment: I think you misunderstand how functions are called. What do you mean by 'for looped'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript's [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object

```
function hover() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var length = args.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(args[i]).onmouseover = 
            function () { this.style.backgroundColor = "orange"; }
        document.getElementById(args[i]).onmouseout = 
            function () { this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; }
    }
}
```

---

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Zg56n/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="h1">A</div>
<div id="Hello">B</div>
<div id="box">C</div>
<div id="World">D</div>
```

**JS Call:**

```
hover("h1", "Hello", "box", "World");
```

Comment: hi @Italy thank you.. but where are the arguments? should I still put it one by one?

Comment: Look at the demo I gave you. You can send as Many elements as you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion :

```
<div id="h1">test</div>
<div id="h2">test</div>
<div id="h3">test</div>
<div id="h4">test</div>
```

script, notice the `dummy` variable

```
<script>
function hover(dummy){
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        element.onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor="orange";
        }
        element.onmouseout = function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor="white";
        }
    }
}

//hover('h1','h2','h3','h4');
for (var i=1;i<=24;i++) {
   hover('h'+i);
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with the code you posted. I think I understand the problem you are trying to solve though. Try something like this:

```
function hover(eleId){
  document.getElementById(eleId).style.backgroundColor="orange";
}
for(i=1; i<=24; i++){
  hover("h"+i.toString());
}
```

Also note h1, h2, h3 all look like HTML tags. Check out [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName).